# Capture, save and retrieve images/pictures using Sqlite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In my windows 8 application(C#), I want to capture images (I done) and then save it to a Sqlite database. As Sqlite is not supporting BipmapImage, Uri types etc (I tried but giving exceptions of not supported storage..) How can I do this?

I simply want to save images in local database that I have captured using camera and then retrieve these images (set to binding). Please suggest me other options to achieve this.

I also tried to convert Uri into string and then saving this string into SQLite db and then again converting string to Uri and then making Bitmap images but I couldn't achieve this (is it a right approach ?).

If you can share me any sample please do it. I spent many hours in it but don't know where I am doing wrong!

Thanks Zauk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I do not prefer to save images in a database.

But if you want to save images in the database then one way of doing this is to convert your images to `base64` string and then save the string in `SQLite` database.

```
public string ConvertToString(Image image)
{
    // First Convert image to byte array.
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Close();

        byteArray = stream.ToArray();
    }

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);

    return base64String;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save camera captured image into SQLitedatabase in this way..

public class CamActivity extends Activity {

```
byte[] byteArray;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
protected static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
public ImageView imageView;
private DBAdapter db;
byte [] imgbyte;
EditText txtView ;
String name;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db=new DBAdapter(CamActivity.this);
    db.open();
    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
  txtView=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button B = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.camera); 
    B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
           // cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,getImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST ); 
        }
    }); 

    Button save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saving);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
        public void onClick(View v) {




            name=txtView.getText().toString();


            try
            {
```

db.insertImageDetails(byteArray,name);

```
            }              

            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             //mySQLiteAdapter.close();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "processing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "image saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }});

    Button G = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.get);
    G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v)

        {

            Intent intent= new Intent(CamActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

}
        });
    }
```

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    //final byte[] byteArray;
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");   
       //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);    
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
         byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
       System.out.println(byteArray);
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), byteArray.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}



    }
```

Comment: that's a lot of code just to do 1 simple thing don't you think?